# Azure Logs does not have all data

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-log-analytics, azureportal

I have an Azure Function and all calls I can see:

[image]

but when I go to "Logs" and try the following query:

```
traces 
| project
    timestamp,
    message,
    operation_Name,
    operation_Id,
    cloud_RoleName
| where cloud_RoleName =~ 'FunctionDeviceManager' and operation_Name =~ 'FunctionAlertServiceCallback'
| order by timestamp desc
| take 2000
```

I see the following result:

[image]

as we can see, many calls (for example, with id: 95ecc6d554d78fa34534813efb82abba, 29b613056e582666c132de6ff73b2c2e, 29b613056e582666c132de6ff73b2c2e and many others, most of them) are not displayed in the result.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The invocation log is not based on data in the `traces` collection. Instead, it is based on request data. You can easily see so by choosing *Run query in Application Insights*

[image]

It runs this query

```
requests
| project
    timestamp,
    id,
    operation_Name,
    success,
    resultCode,
    duration,
    operation_Id,
    cloud_RoleName,
    invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId']
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where cloud_RoleName =~ 'xxx' and operation_Name =~ 'yyy'
| order by timestamp desc
| take 20
```

So that explains the difference in the result.

Now, regarding the cause of why the traces collection doesn't always contain data related to the request: per default, all types of telemetry are subject to sampling if not specified in the host.json file, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#applicationinsightssamplingsettings).

For example, when you create a new http triggered function using Visual Studio 2022 the following host.json is added

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see request telemetry is excluded from the types of telemetry being sampled. This can cause the issue you are experiencing: the request collection is not sampled, the traces collection is. Hence some data is not in the result list of your query.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is the effect of sampling. Unless you have tweaked your Function App config in `host.json` some executions are skipped in log. As per MS documentation:

> Application Insights has a sampling feature that can protect you from
> producing too much telemetry data on completed executions at times of
> peak load. When the rate of incoming executions exceeds a specified
> threshold, Application Insights starts to randomly ignore some of the
> incoming executions. The default setting for maximum number of
> executions per second is 20 (five in version 1.x). You can configure
> sampling in host.json. Here's an example:

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling